# DI Constructor Injection Page Initialize

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dao, constructor-injection

I use DAO object like Repository pattern and Service and for every service I have interface.

```
public class PerformanceReportService : IPerformanceReportService
{
    private IEmployeeService employeeService;
    private IPersonalMetricsService personalMetricService;
    private IDealStatusService dealStatusService;
    private ISalesPlanService salesPlanService;
    private IMetricServices metricServices;

    public PerformanceReportService(
        IMetricServices metricServices,
        ISalesPlanService salesPlanService,
        IDealStatusService dealStatusService,
        IPersonalMetricsService personalMetricService,
        IEmployeeService employeeService)
    {
    this.employeeService = new employeeService;
    this.metricServices = new metricServices;
    this.personalMetricService = new personalMetricService;
    this.dealStatusService = new dealStatusService;
    this.salesPlanService = new salesPlanService;
}
```

I want to call tihs PerfomanceReportService in the page show down

```
public partial class PerformanceReport : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        private IMetricServices metricServices;
        private ISalesPlanService salesPlanService;
        private IDealStatusService dealStatusService;
        private IPersonalMetricsService personalMetricService;
        private IEmployeeService employeeService;

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            performanceService = new PerformanceReportService(metricServices,salesPlanService,dealStatusService,personalMetricService,employeeService);  
        }
    }  
}
```

I use DAO object like Repository pattern and Service and for every service I have interface.

```
public class PerformanceReportService : IPerformanceReportService
{
    private IEmployeeService employeeService;
    private IPersonalMetricsService personalMetricService;
    private IDealStatusService dealStatusService;
    private ISalesPlanService salesPlanService;
    private IMetricServices metricServices;

    public PerformanceReportService(
        IMetricServices metricServices,
        ISalesPlanService salesPlanService,
        IDealStatusService dealStatusService,
        IPersonalMetricsService personalMetricService,
        IEmployeeService employeeService)
    {
    this.employeeService = new employeeService;
    this.metricServices = new metricServices;
    this.personalMetricService = new personalMetricService;
    this.dealStatusService = new dealStatusService;
    this.salesPlanService = new salesPlanService;
    }
}
```

I want to call tihs PerfomanceReportService in the page show down

```
public partial class PerformanceReport : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        private IMetricServices metricServices;
        private ISalesPlanService salesPlanService;
        private IDealStatusService dealStatusService;
        private IPersonalMetricsService personalMetricService;
        private IEmployeeService employeeService;

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            performanceService = new PerformanceReportService(metricServices,salesPlanService,dealStatusService,personalMetricService,employeeService);  
        }
    }  
}
```

In this case every time my Interface will be **Null**.My question is where I need to put the **new** keyword to bind interface to Class.Just say I don`t use the IoC container still.

Comment: I think line `this.employeeService = new employeeService;` wouldn't even compoile.

Comment: but you do use the new keyword in your constructor e.g. this.employeeService = new employeeService;